# Set TextBox enabled to input without Keyboard.Focus() method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small window in WPF app, it's contain `TextBox` and `Button`. When user click another button I need to make `TextBox` enabled to input text, and besides that I need to set `KeyBoard.Focus()` to the `Button`. Something like that:

```
private void Show() 
{
    textBox.Focus();
    KeyBoard.Focus(button);
}
```

However, its didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: There can be only one element with keyboard focus on the entire desktop. [Keyboard.Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you want to do Exactly? Why `textbox.Focus()` is not enough? Just handle click event of your button and then `textbox.Focus();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want to `TextBox` was active for text input and user can at any time click on the `button` by pressing Enter.

Comment: Then set `IsDefault` property of your button to true, and then handle its click event and int click event `textbox.Focus();`

Comment: let me know If yo made it work or you still need more help?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yep, I made it work, thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one item have keyboard focus. If you want the user to be able to press Enter after entering text, set `IsDefault` to true on the second button.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot!